# SharePoint modern view formatting with JSON: URL returns void

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm trying to format a List in SharePoint modern view.
When clicking on the the URL "Bekijk recept" I get a `javascript:void(0);` instead of opening the URL.

[image: void]

Here you can see some of the code:

```
"elmType": "a",
        "txtContent": "Bekijk recept",
        "style": {
          "border": "none",
          "padding-top": "32px",
          "background-color": "transparent",
          "color": "#0078d7",
          "padding-left": "0px",
          "text-align": "left",
          "cursor": "pointer"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "target": "_blank",
          "href": "[$Linkrecept]"
```

[$Linkrecept] refers to a hyperlink column.

Any ideas why this doesn't work? How can I make the navigation work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on MS Document at [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting), **Column formatting** Supports for static hyperlinks that do not launch script.
You may need to use **Field Customizer** with SPFx that Supports for any hyperlink, including those that invoke custom script

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there is no error in your code. Few thinks to check:

1. Make sure you are using correct **internal name** of your hyperlink field at `[$Linkrecept]`. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)
2. Make sure there is value in your hyperlink field. If field is blank then it will show a link as `javascript:void(0);`.

Workaround for 2nd case is to make your hyperlink field **required** OR you can set the default URL in your code if hyperlink column is blank.

**Sample code**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "rowFormatter":{
        "elmType": "div",
            "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "a",
                "txtContent": "Click here",
                "attributes": {
                    "target": "_blank",
                    "href": "[$HyperlinkCol]"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Workaround if hyperlink field is empty - Set default redirection link**:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
    "rowFormatter":{
        "elmType": "div",
            "children": [
            {
                "elmType": "a",
                "txtContent": "Click here",
                "attributes": {
                    "target": "_blank",
                    "href": "=if([$HyperlinkCol], [$HyperlinkCol], 'https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/')"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)